# Is this code safe using wstring with MultiByteToWideChar?

Tags: c++, winapi

Using `std::wstring` the way I am with `MultiByteToWideChar`?

```
std::wstring widen(const std::string &in)
{
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &in[0], -1, NULL, 0);
    std::wstring out(len, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &in[0], -1, &out[0], len);
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Not checking the return values of winapi functions is always a bad idea.  You certainly won't get away with it if the input string does not in fact contain a utf-8 encoded string, that just creates garbage.

Comment: @HansPassant Should I check the return value on both, or will checking the first one only be fine?

Comment: As hard as I try, I cannot come up with a good reason to only check the first one.  There's just no point to it.

Comment: @Hans: `MultiByteToWideChar` will return 0 on error. The remaining code will therefore produce an empty string (not _garbage_). Checking return values is a good idea, still, even though in this case failure to do so doesn't cause any issues (other than not being able to differentiate between an empty string and an error mode).

Comment: True, it did forget mentioning to use the MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS flag.  An empty string is, arguably, garbage too.  Hard to diagnose garbage, at that.

Comment: @Hans: Agreed. Good advice to use `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` too - I have updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Reading the answers (and the comments) to this question makes me wonder how many people had to implement this kind of function (a lot) and how many of those implementations were flawed (a lot, including mine). This would be worth a blog article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking will it work, probably. Is it correct?

1. You should use `in.c_str()` instead of `&in[0]`
2. You should check the return value of `MultiByteToWideChar` at least the first time.
3. `MultiByteToWideChar` invoked with a (-1) length, if successful, will *include* accounting for a zero-terminator (i.e. it will always return >= 1 on success). The length-constructor for `std::wstring` does not require this. `std::wstring(5,0)` will allocate space for six wide-chars; 5+zero-term. So technically you're allocating one-too-many wide-chars.

From [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs on `cbMultiByte` and -1:

> If this parameter is -1, the function processes the entire input string, including the terminating null character. Therefore, the resulting Unicode string has a terminating null character, and the length returned by the function includes this character.

Comment: `in.c_str()` won't work, have to use `&in[0]`.  Also, I usually pass `in.size()` instead of `-1`, which causes it to not append a null, which means the rest of the code doesn't have to change and becomes correct.

Comment: @Mooing: I don't see why `in.c_str()` wouldn't work and why `&in[0]` would. Both return a `const char*` with the former being zero terminated. Would you mind providing an explanation?

Comment: @MooingDuck A *very* good point on the input string length being passed rather than -1. It doesn't change my comment concerning what happens with the 1-wchar_t oversizing when (-1) *is* passed, but you're absolutely correct that `in.length()` should be used. Now I get to check all the places in my work-code where i do this sort of thing... Thanks for that =P

Comment: @WhozCraig re why `in.c_str()` won't work, it works for the LPCSTR parameter but the LPWSTR parameter won't take a `const char *`.

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem with your first call to `MultiByteToWideChar`: The character sequence is not guaranteed to be zero terminated (although in practice it usually is). Change that line to

```
int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, in.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
```

and you should be safe. Even if `MultiByteToWideChar` fails and returns 0 this is accounted for by passing `len` as the final parameter in the second call to `MultiByteToWideChar`.

With that said, it is safe in the sense that it doesn't crash or corrupt memory. There is, however, one more issue: Unless the input string causes `MultiByteToWideChar` to fail the returned string will claim that its `size()` is one character larger than it should be. I would recommend changing the code as follows:

```cpp
std::wstring widen(std::string const &in)
{
    std::wstring out{};

    if (in.length() > 0)
    {
        // Calculate target buffer size (not including the zero terminator).
        int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
                                      in.c_str(), in.size(), NULL, 0);
        if ( len == 0 )
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid character sequence.");
        }

        out.resize(len);
        // No error checking. We already know, that the conversion will succeed.
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
                            in.c_str(), in.size(), &out[0], out.size());
                            // Use out.data() in place of &out[0] for C++17
    }

    return out;
}
```

This implementation addresses the following issues:

- It reports errors in case the input sequence is not valid UTF-8, by passing the `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag.
- Errors are reported by throwing exceptions. That makes it possible to distinguish between conversion errors and a successful call, that returns a zero-sized string. (*Note: The `std::wstring` c'tor already throws exceptions in case of failure. It would feel unnatural to **not** throw exceptions for other errors.*)
- The implementation properly deals with input containing embedded `NUL` characters. This is rarely used, but when it is (e.g. when composing the [OPENFILENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamew)'s *lpstrFilter* member), it won't (silently) fail for that reason.
- It doesn't over-allocate the return value's container storage. In case the *cbMultiByte* argument is set to `-1` in a call to `MultiByteToWideChar`, the returned length **does include** space for the zero terminator. This character, however, is owned by the `std::string` implementation, and not part of the character sequence to be converted.
- Related to the previous bullet point, this implementation doesn't convert the zero terminator. The original code did, and the returned string produces 2 `NUL` characters at the end of the string, when the `c_str()` member is invoked.

Comment: why do people not pass the length of the input string?  That avoids the too big issue.

Comment: @Mooning: Changed the code appropriately. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: It looks like this code throws an error when given an empty input string. Perhaps it should return an empty std::wstring instead?

Comment: @use: The API call [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar#return-value) the number of characters written. If you pass in an empty string, it returns `1`.

Comment: @IInspectable The function doesn't write the null terminator if a size is supplied, so it returns `0`, not `1`. The docs also say "Note that, if cbMultiByte is 0, the function fails." (i.e. returns 0)

Comment: @use: You are right. I've changed the implementation so that it doesn't throw an exception when passed an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

No, since a `std::wstring` is not guaranteed to store it's data in a contiguous block of memory (though it most likely does in your implementation). Use a `std::vector<wchar_t>` instead.

Comment: `std::wstring` is guaranteed to store the sequence of characters in a contiguous block of memory. This is not spelled out explicitly in the standard. However, since `c_str()` has to return in constant time there is no way to store the sequence other then in a contiguous block.

Comment: @Tim: In the current standard, contiguous storage is spelled out explicitly. §21.4.1/5: "The char-like objects in a basic_string object shall be stored contiguously."

Comment: @Jerry: Thanks for the information. I suppose my 1998-based knowledge requires an overhaul.

Comment: @Tim: Hmm, but even if the complexity of `c_str()` implies that the character sequences is stored in a contiguous block, you still have no implication that `&s[0]` yields a pointer to the beginning of this block, do you? Or is there some law which says that `s.c_str() + i` has to yield the same address as `&s[i]`?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Ah, that's good news. I have to check my code for places which use a `std::vector` just to copy the data into a `std::string`. :-)

Comment: @Frerich: §21.4.7.1/1: `const charT* c_str() const noexcept;` _"Returns: A pointer p such that p + i == &operator[](i) for each i in [0,size()]."_ (I finally arrived in this millenium, this is from ISO/IEC 14882:2011)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good but I want to add some extra information for future visitors based on my own research into the same issue.

1. Microsoft developer, Larry Osterman, has [a good blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2015/11/24/converting-win32-api-results-to-stdwstring-or-stdstring/) describing such a function with a very good point about the return code checking and NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization). You should read the post for discussion if it's still available.  I'm including his final code just in case the post goes missing.

   ```
   std::wstring UnicodeStringFromAnsiString(_In_ const std::string &ansiString)
   {
       std::wstring returnValue;
       auto wideCharSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, ansiString.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0);
       if (wideCharSize == 0)
       {
           return returnValue;
       }
       returnValue.resize(wideCharSize);
       wideCharSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, ansiString.c_str(), -1, &returnValue[0], wideCharSize);
       if (wideCharSize == 0)
       {
           returnValue.resize(0);
           return returnValue;
       }
       returnValue.resize(wideCharSize-1);
       return returnValue;
   }
   ```

In my own usage, I was able to add the optimization mentioned in the blog comments and not need -1 for the ANSI string length.

2. C++17 (Section 21.3.1.7.1) documents a newly-added non-const `data()` method which should be used instead of `&in[0]` to get a mutable pointer.

   ```
   charT* data() noexcept;
   ```
3. STL owns the trailing `\0` in the `c_str()` results so be careful how you manipulate the string size.

Comment: Frankly, this has got to be the first time, where I absolutely, positively **must** disagree with Larry Osterman. The code has 3 issues: `1` It allocates one character too many (only to resize it back in the final step). `2` It does not account for embedded NUL characters (`std::string` allows to have those). `3` It doesn't report errors properly (are you really going to check whether the returned string is empty and the source string is not?). It's completely unclear, why the code doesn't use the input string length.

Comment: Well, `4` the implementation checks the return value of the second call to `MultiByteToWideChar`, although it knows that it **cannot** possibly fail. It operates on the same input, and just made sure, that the output is valid.