# How to marshall utf-8 bytestring via COM variant?

Tags: c++, utf-8, com, variant

I have a code to pass some utf-8 encoded JSON string via COM variant, specifically using CComVariant. Everything worked well until my software was installed on computer of Japanese user, I suppose he is working with Japanese version of Windows 7. And somehow that Windows decided to change bytes sequence for 1 non-ascii character and broke JSON formatting.

Problem with combination:

```
"nić" (bytes: 0x22 0x6E 0x69 0xC4 0x87 0x22)
```

after it was packed to CComVariant and then unpacked back the string above has changed to:

```
"niāE (bytes: 0x22 0x6E 0x69 0xC4 0x81 0x45)
```

I.e. combination `ć"` became `āE`.

My code works as following (simplified version):

```
void get_json(VARIANT *out)
{
    const std::string json = "\"nić\"";
    CComVariant result = json.c_str();
    result.Detach(out);
}
```

then in other part of code:

```
CComVariant varJson;
get_json(&varJson);
const std::string utf8json = std::string(CStringA(varJson));
// At this point utf8json is not the same as original json above
// and cannot be decoded properly by JSON parser.
```

It seems I misunderstood something about CStringA in COM Variant, and passing UTF-8 bytes here was not safe. I can't reproduce this problem with Western Europe's version of Windows, this is somehow related to Japanese version.

Comment: The source string is encoded in utf-8.  But CComVariant does not know that, it will always use the system default code page.  The odds that it is utf-8 are very close to zero.  Well, zero.  You must use std::wstring to prevent such accidental encoding problems.  Where that needs to start is not clear from the question, as early as possible of course.  If your json parser is too wonky then convert yourself with MultiByteToWideChar() using CP_UTF8.

Comment: The only applicable VARIANT for UTF-8 bytes, is, well, an array of bytes. If you convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16, you could use a BSTR—a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units. (Sorry, if I'm changing the mix of MFC, ATL and Win32 API here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was explained in the comments. As for the solution, because you're using `std` (there are plenty other solutions), I suggest you use the `widen` function defined in this answer on SO: [Is this code safe using wstring with MultiByteToWideChar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184709/is-this-code-safe-using-wstring-with-multibytetowidechar)
and change the code to:

```
CComVariant result = widen(json).c_str();
```

Let's check under the debugger. Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Now, the VARIANT (or it's contained BSTR) is fine.

Note if you need a byte string equivalent from this VARIANT or from a BSTR (do you really?), don't convert it back with a broken code like this: `std::string(CStringA(varJson))`, again, use a reverse equivalent of `widen`, based on `WideCharToMultiByte` this time.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 ways to fix this:

1. (As suggested) convert utf-8 encoded string representation of my json objects to proper unicode strings as Variant expected
2. (slightly more complex) convert any non-ascii characters in my string to unicode-escape sequences like `\u1234` therefore ensure all my data are pure ascii.

Due to backward-compatibility restrictions I have to go second route.